# div background color not working with inputs floated left

Tags: html, css

I need the following div to have a background color - simple right. But, it doesn't work correctly. I've done some testing, and figured out its the floats on the spans that are screwing it up. So, how do i fix this?

```
.days{
background-color:#000;
}

span {
display:block;
width:200px;
float:left; 
}

<div class="days">
        <span>  
        <input id="Field9" name="Field9" type="checkbox"  value=""   size="3" maxlength="4" tabindex="4"  />
        <label class="days" >Monday</label>
        </span> <span>
        <input id="Field5" name="Field10" type="checkbox"  value="" size="3" maxlength="4" tabindex="4"    />
        <label   class="days" >Tuesday</label>
        </span> <span>
        <input id="Field5" name="Field11" type="checkbox"  value="" size="3" maxlength="4" tabindex="4"    />
        <label   class="days"  >Wednesday</label>
        </span> <span>  
    <!-- goes till sunday --!>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get rid of `display:block;` on your `span` tags, floated elements do not obey the `display` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you float elements, you take them out of the normal flow of the document, and as a result, other non-floated elements do not make room for them.

What you're observing is that your div no longer takes the full height of its child elements because they're floated. All you need to do is to "clear" or undo the floating, and make `days` take the full height, and its background color will show. My preferred way of clearing floats is to give your containing element `overflow: hidden`:

```
.days
{
    background-color:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

For more info about clearing floats, check out the [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) article about it, which includes an explanation of the `overflow: hidden` method.

Comment: sweet that fixed it, but I don't understand why. can you please explain how overflow hidden works, because according to the w3schools overflow hidden clips the overflow, and the rest of the content will be invisible

Comment: There are three popular methods of clearing floats. One is to use `overflow: hidden`, which is my method of choice (it's a one liner). The other is to put an extra element with `clear: both` before the closing tag of your `div`, and the third is to use the CSS `content` attribute. I'll update my answer with relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

You can either apply the `background-color` to the `<span>`, set a height to the `<div class="days">`, or put a `<div>` below the `<span>` with the CSS `clear:both;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not able to change the background color of the div. You can see the fixed version at http://jsfiddle.net/FazXG/2/